# Graphing with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, graph

```
function aloop()
{
    var count = 0;
    var stars;

    stars = newCost;
    document.eMarkForm.dangerRange.value =  document.eMarkForm.dangerRange.value + "\n" + newCost + " " ;

    for (var count = 1; count <= stars; count = count + 1)
    {
        document.eMarkForm.dangerRange.value = document.eMarkForm.dangerRange.value + "*" ;
    }
}
```

so im calculating an amount called newCost and I want it to display in my dangerRange text field with a * beside the value. However I want 1 * to appear for every 10 in the amount of newCost. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you only care about the final result (if it is 23, display `23**`?) or do you want to display intermediate results too (see the counting on screen)?

Answer (score 0):

In your 'for' loop, increment 'count' by 10: `count = count + 10` and change the comparison operator to '<': `count < stars`. If you always want at least one star, start 'count' at 0, otherwise start it at 10.